# Distribute New Unity3D Game on iOS without App Store

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, app-store

I want to know, is it possible to distribute new Unity3D Game without using AppStore for iOS?
I will have one host application with native on iOS Appstore, which can load different unity based games.

Now Can I push new game to devices from my server directly without updating the application on AppStore?

I understand that Assets can be updated via downloading package from my server.
But here requirement is to distribute completely new application.

Please suggest.

Regards
Sandip Patel

Comment: no, but you can download entire HTML games (e.g. made in Phaser, Construct 2, GameMaker,...) and run it in a webview, if that is an option for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot download code to iOS apps. Apple will reject that.

If you ship all the code in your app, but just make the assets purchased downloads, then that can work.

Docs:

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

> 2.7 Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected